# Jetbrains DataGrip cannot add a new SQL Server connection without specifying a concrete database

Tags: datagrip

I have multiple SQL databases which are on the same host SQL server. I'm trying to add a new Data Source - entered a connection URL (without specifying a database name), selected needed schemas in the Schema tab but then, when I click on either Apply or OK button, nothing happens.

Can someone give me advice what is wrong here?

[General tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OvRE.png)
[Schemas tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEPTz.png)

If I try to input a connection URL with a concrete database name - Data Source is being successfully created.

Comment: Once you click Ok, do you receive a successful connection? You can also check the idea log in Help - Show Log in Files and see if there are any errors. Look for string: connecting to:

Comment: No, just literally nothing happened after clicking on OK. Tried another approach and it works, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did it.

I decided to give this a try:

- firstly add a new Data Source [Add new Data Source without specifying database name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLWEl.png)
- then right click on created Data Source and load all Schemas [Load Schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohklo.png)
- wait till they are loaded - it's visible in the left lower corner [Schemas loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg7QX.png)
- select needed Schemas [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95a9x.png)
- voila [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8FKf.png)